# How to catch error when cross-domain request option method send

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

Is there any possibility to catch the error when cross-domain requestion option method send?

Here is the code snippet

```js
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

ajax.getJSON(XXXX)
    .catch(err => {
        const { xhr } = err;

        if (xhr.status === 0) {
            window.console.log('Server is not responding');
        } else {
            window.console.log(xhr);
        }

        return Observable.of();
    });
```

I don't want this error shown in the console:

[image: console error message]

Comment: it is really harmless to show it on console. Why

Comment: You are right! I just want to know if any possibility avoid it. ^^